# Perform calculations on two rows from UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT count
FROM (
    SELECT count(id) as count FROM listens
    WHERE user='None'
    UNION
    SELECT count(id) as count FROM listens
    WHERE user!='None'
) as details
```

which returns

```
count
36793
112755
```

I would like to perform the division on the two values (e.g. `36793 / 112755`) so that the output from my query is

```
count
0.3263092546
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `union` at all!  Here is a much simpler way of writing the query:

```
SELECT sum(user = 'None') / sum(user <> 'None')
FROM listens;
```

MySQL treats a boolean expression as a number in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  The above counts the number of values that match the conditions.

If you want to be verbose or to be compatible with other dialects of SQL, you can do:

```
SELECT (sum(case when user = 'None' then 1 else 0 end) /
        sum(case when user <> 'None' then 1 end)
       ) as ratio
FROM listens;
```

I don't see a particular advantage to the verbosity if you are using MySQL, but the logic is equivalent.

Comment: Use count(), not sum().

Comment: I think that will need to be a case statement within the `SUM` function

Comment: @JulioD . . . `COUNT()` would return the wrong answer, so I don't think that would be appropriate.

Comment: @JulioD  it should be `sum` as `sum(user = 'None')` will count all the listeners where the user is 'None'. How? When `user = 'None` is true, 1 is returned and when it's false 0 is returned. Summing such values is like counting them. Using count instead will be wrong as it will count the zeros.

Comment: Oh I see. Well explained @cdaiga , got it!